# load json with encoded unicode object

Tags: python, json, unicode

i have a json file with thease elements:

> {"created_at":"Sun Jan 03 09:12:55 +0000
>   2016","id":683576764392579072,"id_str":"683576764392579072","text":"\u067e\u06cc\u0627\u0645
>   \u062a\u0633\u0644\u06cc\u062a \u0631\u0626\u06cc\u0633
>   \u0645\u062c\u0644\u0633 \u062e\u0628\u0631\u06af\u0627\u0646
>   \u062f\u0631 \u067e\u06cc \u0634\u0647\u0627\u062f\u062a
>   \u0634\u06cc\u062e \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0645\u0631
>   \u007bshahrekhabar\u007d https://t.co/ML75s9CTYX","source":"\u003ca
>   href=\"http://ifttt.com\"
>   rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":4678224625,"id_str":"4678224625","name":"victor
>   ward","screen_name":"victorward983","location":null,"url":null,"description":null,"protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":13,"friends_count":0,"listed_count":8,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":7262,"created_at":"Wed Dec 30 13:21:18 +0000
>   2015","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"2B7BB9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/682190595184394240/0zFJDnmW_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/682190595184394240/0zFJDnmW_normal.jpg","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/ML75s9CTYX","expanded_url":"http://bit.ly/1W7F7X4","display_url":"bit.ly/1W7F7X4","indices":[65,88]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"fa","timestamp_ms":"1451812375530"}

when i want to load it with below code:

```
aaa=f.read()
data = json.loads(aaa)
print(data)
```

python get into this error :

> ....  raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 2208)

when i use this code:

```
aaa=f.read()
data = json.loads(aaa.decode("utf-8"))
print(data)
```

it gives me this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

how can i load a json with decoded Unicode element?

Comment: I think you need to use jsom dump. look here https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-xml-json/

Comment: @Umair it gives me this error: TypeError: Object of type 'TextIOWrapper' is not JSON serializable